# How do I install Pinta?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, ppa

I ordered a new computer with Windows 8 to test before rolling out. It arrived with Ubuntu 12.04. Rather then just send it back, I decided to check it out first as I think the system is probably much better than the MS options. However, try as I might, I cannot get a PPA set up. I'm trying to install Pinta-Paint but can't find the line to copy into the software centre. Please could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at their HP: http://pinta-project.com/download.ashx there are plenty of options to install it: http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Pinta Repository - Ubuntu Precise**

Pinta is available in a software repository, or PPA. In an Ubuntu-based Linux distribution it is very easy to add a new PPA to your software repository lists to install new software or provide system updates.

For more information on PPA's [click here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

After installing a repository one of the easiest ways to install almost any application is to use the Ubuntu Software Center. If you already have this in your repository list continue to Installing Pinta via the [Ubuntu Software Center](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx#installing%20pinta%20via%20the%20ubuntu%20software%20center).

Copy, one line at a time, to install the following PPA to get the latest stable release and paste them in a terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
```

Once you've installed the above PPA, then you must update you system with their package lists. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once you have a PPA setup with Pinta on it and have updated your package list, you are now ready to install Pinta.

---

**Installing Pinta via the Terminal**

Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>key-shortcut and after the PPA has been setup (see above), you can easily install Pinta from the terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

---

**Installing** [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx) **via the Ubuntu Software Center**:

Once you have the PPA's setup and your system updated with their package list, now we can install Pinta via the Ubuntu Software Center:

1. Launch the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Search for `pinta`
3. Click the 'Install' button to install Pinta.
4. Once it is installed you can now use Pinta. Navigate to: `Menu` ▸ `Graphics` ▸ `Pinta` (This is the default location in most menu systems. Your results may vary.)

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to install it via the Ubuntu Software Center (couldn't find the 'terminal') although I didn't need to add 'sudo apt' as it wouldn't accept it. All I needed was from 'ppa'. Not sure that's right, but it worked! Many thanks although I could really do with understanding it a bit better. All the info I can find seems to assume I know more than I do!

Comment: @user268531: I added the terminal key-shortcuts to 'Installing Pinta via the Terminal'. Please accept my answer! http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: The terminal emulator in Linux is like the Command Prompt that people are using in Windows. Since you'll be needing it for many, many operations in Ubuntu Linux, you should know that you can open the terminal emulator by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T or by searching for it typing **terminal** in the search field.

Comment: ppa is out of date and not supported for current versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the repo hasn't moved it should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moonlight-team/pinta
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pinta
```

See also the installation section here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/pinta-paint-net-clone-adds-new-tools-features

Comment: I was trying to install Pinta by typing given above commands  _ 
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead._

Comment: I think this link can be of help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 2):

I only know about Pinta package but I have also found something else called Pinta – Paint.NET clone for linux. If you want to install this one, all you have to do is to type the following codes in a terminal emulator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moonlight-team/pinta
```

Input your password when asked for it, and press Enter to add the ppa to your Software Sources list. Next type these codes in the same terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

If you want to install latest stable release for Pinta (image editing software, Gimp replacement) then you can use these codes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

I never used the first one (Pinta – Paint.NET) but I am guessing this is the one you want since Pinta image editing package is already present in the Software Center list.

Comment: Yes - installed Pinta now. Hadn't realized I could find it in the Software Center List! Guess I have a ways to go to catch up! Still, it will be an interesting journey.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of November **2017**, there seems to be **no working ppa** (neither moonlight-team nor pinta-maintainers).
Version 1.6 can still be installed from the Ubuntu **Software Center** and works mostly well.
A **developer** wrote in July 2017: Pinta development ["has certainly slowed down - I haven't had very much free time to work on it lately."](https://answers.launchpad.net/pinta/+question/650543) Hopefully this will change again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want version 2.x of Pinta, you can install it from the Snap Store, either via the terminal:

```
snap install pinta
```

... or through the *Ubuntu Software* app - making sure to pick the Snap Store option and not the deb option if you find multiple results when searching for "Pinta":

[image: Screenshot showing installation via the Ubuntu Software app]

Note that installing via the PPA, as suggested by older answers here (and indeed still presented as an option at https://www.pinta-project.com/howto/installing-pinta) will give you version 1.x of Pinta, and merely adding the PPA will display a message recommending that you use another installation approach instead:

> $ `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable`
> Repository: 'deb
> https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/
> jammy main'
> Description:
> Note: this PPA only provides GTK2 builds of Pinta (1.7.x) and is no longer updated for Pinta 2.0 and later. Installing the flatpak or snap package is recommended instead.
>
> It is strongly recommended to also ensure that Mono 6.10 or higher is
> installed on your system (run `mono --version` to check), as earlier
> 6.x versions can produce random crashes. You can install the latest Mono version from
> https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin
> More info:
> [https://launchpad.net/~pinta-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/pinta-stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Epinta-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/pinta-stable)
> Adding repository. Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.

I would suggest using one of the officially recommended methods for your first try at installing Pinta. That said, I have repeatedly experienced major bugs and crashes with Pinta on Ubuntu, across many combinations of Ubuntu version and Pinta version, so it is worth bearing the PPA installation method from other answers here in mind as an alternative if version 2.x installed via Snap doesn't work properly for you - perhaps an older version will!

Answer (score 0):

To install pinta in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install pinta
```