# Can't install missing application packages in 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, pinta

```
mike@mike-desktop:~$ pinta
The program 'pinta' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install pinta
mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo apt install pinta
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pinta
```

This is not the only app I am having trouble with, geany is also missing plugins and Rhythmbox is missing MPEG-4 AAC despite installing the usual extras
This is a fresh install of 16.04, and remounting my home drive after install as usual.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (65).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then trying to play anything gives

> Required plugin could not be found
>
> Rhythmbox requires to install plugins to play media files of the
>   following type: MPEG-4 AAC decoder

Normally fixing things is easy, but this time after trying, apt, aptitude,  software center (missing a lot in here) etc no joy - they just dont appear to exist.

Comment: pinta is in Universe. http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: Hello @Mike, this link can be of help http://askubuntu.com/questions/447299/how-do-i-install-pinta

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem if you add the necessary repositories, then update, and finally install the software for which you have added the repository... An example for your actual problem is found in the link in the comment I made above or you can also go here https://launchpad.net/~pinta-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/pinta-stable

Comment: Please try this and give me the feed back @Mike

Comment: So you are saying that in 16.04 we now need to add all these packages by hand ? that is surprising to me since so many things I use are missing even basics like git send-email which usually works with "apt-get install git-email"

Comment: @yufenyuy: there is no xenial release in the Pinta Stable PPA.  If you use the Pinta Unstable / Daily PPA and manually copy the 1.7.x 15.10 release to another PPA for the Xenial 16.04 series, it will fail to install with dependency conflicts.  In summary, I don't think the Pinta PPAs give anything newer to Xenial 16.04 than what is already in the main 16.04 repositories.

Comment: @rik-shaw okay I now get it... that's why voted up your comment.